# Sending text inside button over tcp ip

Tags: android, eclipse, button, text, tcp

i want to sent some text into the server. what i want is the text inside the button. i mean the button contain a text to send into the server

**here's my activity.java**

```
textout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    Button buttonOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button buttonYES = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    buttonOK.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}
    Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.43.15", 8888);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                OutputStream out1 = socket.getOutputStream();      

                TextView textout = null;
                textout.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());             
                textout.setText("OKAY");
```

and

**here is my server.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
 try {
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
   System.out.println("Listening :8888");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  while(true){
   try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
```

Now, i've got problem when i clicked the OK button, the text won't shows in my server. but the connection between client and server has already established. and suddenly my app force close.

it's the logcat shows

```
07-06 22:06:54.880: I/dalvikvm(590): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 22:06:54.936: I/dalvikvm(590): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

and here's my server shows

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at MyServer.main(MyServer.java:31)
```

what should i do to make the text shows in my server.
please help me. thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the logcat? I have a feeling you are getting a NPE

Comment: 07-06 22:06:54.880: I/dalvikvm(590): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-06 22:06:54.936: I/dalvikvm(590): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually sending the text. I would try
`doas.write(text.getBytes())` first...

Comment: Where you want the text to be sent.